# OpenCV Watershed - Options to modify code to obtain better results - otherwise what will work for my needs

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, watershed

I am using Raspberry Pi Zero, Python 3 script and OpenCV.
I am trying to create a single pixel continuous path that delineates 'hard' surface from 'soft' surface in images like this:
[image: Original]
The image I want to end up with is 'the RED line (on the below JPG) on a solid white background' (overlaid on Original just to show its location). I hope to be able to get a relatively smooth result within about 10 pixels of my desired path:
[image: Desired-overlay]

So far I have come to believe that I should be able to use cv.watershed as the main function to achieve this but the results so far are not so good.
To simplify my OpenCV learning curve I have modified the watershed.py example.
Before I use watershed, I do a 150 pixel radius Gausian Blurr which gives me the best results so far.
Then I place two watershed markers, one on each side of the image, and try to have watershed define the border that I want.

Here is the Python script that uses watershed (sorry to use incorrect snippet but code sample insertion did not work):

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Watershed segmentation
=========
This program demonstrates the watershed segmentation algorithm
in OpenCV: watershed().
Usage
-----
watershed.py [image filename]
Keys
----
  1-7   - switch marker color
  SPACE - update segmentation
  r     - reset
  a     - toggle autoupdate
  ESC   - exit
'''


# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

class Sketcher:
    def __init__(self, windowname, dests, colors_func):
        self.prev_pt = None
        self.windowname = windowname
        self.dests = dests
        self.colors_func = colors_func
        self.dirty = False
        self.show()
        cv.setMouseCallback(self.windowname, self.on_mouse)

    def show(self):
        cv.imshow(self.windowname, self.dests[0])

    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        pt = (x, y)
        if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.prev_pt = pt
        elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            self.prev_pt = None

        if self.prev_pt and flags & cv.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
            for dst, color in zip(self.dests, self.colors_func()):
                cv.line(dst, self.prev_pt, pt, color, 5)
            self.dirty = True
            self.prev_pt = pt
            self.show()


class App:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.img = cv.imread(fn)
        if self.img is None:
            raise Exception('Failed to load image file: %s' % fn)

        h, w = self.img.shape[:2]
        self.markers = np.zeros((h, w), np.int32)
        self.markers_vis = self.img.copy()
        self.cur_marker = 1
        self.colors = np.int32( list(np.ndindex(2, 2, 2)) ) * 255

        self.auto_update = True
        self.sketch = Sketcher('img', [self.markers_vis, self.markers], self.get_colors)

    def get_colors(self):
        return list(map(int, self.colors[self.cur_marker])), self.cur_marker

    def watershed(self):
        m = self.markers.copy()
        cv.watershed(self.img, m)
        overlay = self.colors[np.maximum(m, 0)]
        oim = cv.imread('1.JPG')
        vis = cv.addWeighted(oim, 0.5, overlay, 0.5, 0.0, dtype=cv.CV_8UC3)
        cv.imshow('watershed', vis)

    def run(self):
        while cv.getWindowProperty('img', 0) != -1 or cv.getWindowProperty('watershed', 0) != -1:
            ch = cv.waitKey(50)
            if ch == 27:
                break
            if ch >= ord('1') and ch <= ord('7'):
                self.cur_marker = ch - ord('0')
                print('marker: ', self.cur_marker)
            if ch == ord(' ') or (self.sketch.dirty and self.auto_update):
                self.watershed()
                self.sketch.dirty = False
            if ch in [ord('a'), ord('A')]:
                self.auto_update = not self.auto_update
                print('auto_update if', ['off', 'on'][self.auto_update])
            if ch in [ord('r'), ord('R')]:
                self.markers[:] = 0
                self.markers_vis[:] = self.img
                self.sketch.show()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = '1-gb150.JPG'
    print(__doc__)
    App(fn).run()
```

Here is the best watershed I have seen so far:
[image: Watershed results]

What further watershed/process options can I use or if watershed is not the best approach for this problem, what other approach can be added/used instead?

(Edit: As far as execution time I would need 1-2 seconds on a Raspberry Pi Zero)

(Edit 7/3/2018 #1: Conditions that might help further define algorithm rules to simplify process.

1. My desired path would never be islands.
2. My desired path could be reduced to lines that enter one image edge and leave another image edge while taking the 'straightest' path along the way. Image sequence could always start in that state.
3. Perhaps if any corner is reached the algorithm could stop and ask for assistance. (ie to handle encountering an image that has > 90 degree corner in it).
4. The image series will always have some point on the desired line that was determined from a previous image, that could be used as a starting pixel for a 'edge following' algorithm in the new image (edge following gets difficult when grass grows over edge, but I could weed-eat first).

(Edit: More hard/soft surface images I need to use algorithm on):
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(end more)

Comment: The problem with this problem is that you'll find a solution that works on this image, but will not work in general. You'll go to the next area in the same yard, and the "soft surface" will look slightly differently, and you'll get a wrong result. Next you'll go to a different yard, where the "hard surface" has a different texture, and the results will be even worse. This type of project should start with the collection of a lot of different images, trying to cover most variation you're expecting to find in practice.

Comment: I realize those issues but I am only concerned about my 2000 feet of edge and I believe I am working with this 'worst' case image. Using your argument, there would be no driveless cars because all images are different, you have to start somewhere, thanks for input.  I will also show 12 more 'easier' images if that helps with an answer. I think there is definitely texture differences and hue differences, and frequency of 'straight' edges on my hard surfaces.

Comment: Cool, you've got lots of examples. Now manually annotate them, and stick them in a deep learning algorithm and you're done! -- This is how they do the "driverless" cars (which are not driverless because there must always be a human ready to take over), except that those companies have hundreds of people annotating years worth of footage.

Comment: Seeing the variation is helpful, though. Maybe you could try to detect curves, then classify them based on curvature. Though stains on the pavement could lead to errors there too.

Comment: But I don't want HAL to do it, I want to understand.  Maybe I need to try a Lee Morphological edge detector :) Yes curvature was also on my mind, these are pretty straight with some angled corners.  What function detects curves?

Comment: I approve of that sentiment!

Comment: You can use Canny, or maybe even [phase congruency](https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/index.html#phasecong) to extract curves, then compute curvature simply by locally approximating those curves with a 2nd degree polynomial.

Comment: So you think I should install Octave on my Pi and figure out how to implement your ideas, it will take a lot of learning for my 60 year old brain but that is what life is about, till you die? (love that link)

Comment: I really like MATLAB, but you can implement phase congruency fairly easily also in Python with OpenCV (well, easy once you figure out how it works). Maybe my ideas are not the simplest. :)

Comment: Cris, stains on surfaces could be eliminated because they would be islands, see edit at bottom of question for other limiting criteria that might be OK.

Comment: How about GrabCut?

Comment: I played with the GrabCut demo but had even less luck than watershed, especially when I want to do this as automatic as I can.  Is there a way to use GrabCut in a way differently than the demo does?

Comment: I have pretty much decided that watershed is not the answer but I have come up with a Gimp procedure that is close and I need an OpenCV version of it that I can tweek. I started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193713/opencv-python-script-from-gimp-procedure) .  If it works I will post it here as an answer.