# OpenCV Python script from Gimp procedure - Grass/Hard surface edge detection

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision

I would like to develop a Python OpenCV script to duplicate/improve on a Gimp procedure I have developed.  The goal of the procedure is to provide an x,y point array that follows the dividing line between grass and hard surfaces. This array will allow me to finish my 500 lb 54" wide pressure washing robot, which has a Raspberry Pi Zero (and camera), so that it can follow that edge at a speed of a couple inches per second.  I will be monitoring and/or controlling the bot via its wifi video stream and an iPhone app while I watch TV on my couch.

Here is a sample original image (60x80 pixels):

[image]

The Gimp procedure is:

1. Convert image to indexed 2 colors. Basically grass on one side and bricks or pavement on the other side.  DARN SHADOWS oops that's me :)

[image]

2. Of the two colors, take the lower Hue value and magic wand on a pixel of that value with the below wand settings.  The Hue setting of 23 is how I remove shadows and the feather setting of 15 is how I remove islands/jaggies (grass in the cracks :).

[image]

3. Do an advanced selection to path with the following advanced settings values (changes from default values are yellow). Basically I want just line segments and my (x,y) point array will be the Yellow path dots.

[image]

4. Next I export the path to an .xml file from which I can parse and isolate the yellow dots in the above image.  Here is the .xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="0.833333in" height="1.11111in"
     viewBox="0 0 60 80">
  <path id="Selection"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 60.00,0.00
           C 60.00,0.00 60.00,80.00 60.00,80.00
             60.00,80.00 29.04,80.00 29.04,80.00
             29.04,80.00 29.04,73.00 29.04,73.00
             29.04,73.00 30.00,61.00 30.00,61.00
             30.00,61.00 30.00,41.00 30.00,41.00
             30.00,41.00 29.00,30.85 29.00,30.85
             29.00,30.85 24.00,30.85 24.00,30.85
             24.00,30.85 0.00,39.00 0.00,39.00
             0.00,39.00 0.00,0.00 0.00,0.00
             0.00,0.00 60.00,0.00 60.00,0.00 Z" />
</svg>
```

My goal for execution time for this OpenCV procedure on my Pi Zero is about 1-2 seconds or less (currently taking ~0.18 secs).

I have cobbled together something that sortof results in the sameish points that are in the Gimp xml file.  I am not sure at all if it is doing what Gimp does with regard to the hue range of the mask. I have not yet figured out how to apply the minimum radius on the mask, I am pretty sure I will need that when the mask gets a 'grass' clump on the edge of the hard surface as part of the mask.  Here are all the contour points so far (ptscanvas.bmp):

[image]

As of 7/6/2018 5:08 pm EST, here is the 'still messy' script that sortof works and found those points;

```html
import numpy as np
import time, sys, cv2

img = cv2.imread('2-60.JPG')
cv2.imshow('Original',img)
# get a blank pntscanvas for drawing points on 
pntscanvas = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

print (sys.version)  
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Python 3 or a more recent version is required.")

def doredo():
    start_time = time.time()

    # Use kmeans to convert to 2 color image
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    Z = hsv_img.reshape((-1,3))
    Z = np.float32(Z)
    # define criteria, number of clusters(K) 
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    K = 2
    ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    # Create a mask by selecting a hue range around the lowest hue of the 2 colors
    if center[0,0] < center[1,0]:
        hueofinterest = center[0,0]
    else:
        hueofinterest = center[1,0]
    hsvdelta = 8
    lowv = np.array([hueofinterest - hsvdelta, 0, 0])
    higv = np.array([hueofinterest + hsvdelta, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lowv, higv)

    # Extract contours from the mask
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    # Find the biggest area contour
    cnt = contours[0]
    max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

    for cont in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cont) > max_area:
            cnt = cont
            max_area = cv2.contourArea(cont)

    # Make array of all edge points of the largets contour, named allpnts  
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) # 0.0125*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) seems to work better
    allpnts = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Elapsed cv2 time was %g seconds" % (end_time - start_time))

    # Convert back into uint8, and make 2 color image for saving and showing
    center = np.uint8(center)
    res = center[label.flatten()]
    res2 = res.reshape((hsv_img.shape))

    # Save, show and print stuff
    cv2.drawContours(pntscanvas, allpnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imwrite("pntscanvas.bmp", pntscanvas)
    cv2.imshow("pntscanvas.bmp", pntscanvas)
    print('allpnts')
    print(allpnts)
    print("center")
    print(center)
    print('lowv',lowv)
    print('higv',higv)
    cv2.imwrite('mask.bmp',mask)
    cv2.imshow('mask.bmp',mask)
    cv2.imwrite('CvKmeans2Color.bmp',res2)
    cv2.imshow('CvKmeans2Color.bmp',res2)

print ("Waiting for 'Spacebar' to Do/Redo OR 'Esc' to Exit")
while(1):
    ch = cv2.waitKey(50)
    if ch == 27:
        break
    if ch == ord(' '):
        doredo()
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Left to do:

1. Add mask radiusing on non-edge pixels to take care of raw masks like this one that Gimp creates before it runs a min radius on the mask:

[image]

1a. EDIT: As of July 9, 2018, I have been concentrating on this issue as it seems to be my biggest problem. I am unable to have cv2.findcontours smooth out the 'edge grass' as well as Gimp does with its magic wand radius feature.  Here on the left, is a 2 colour 'problem' mask and the overlaid resultant 'Red' points that are found directly using cv2.findcontours and on the right, the Gimp radiused mask applied to the left images 'problem' mask before cv2.findcontours is applied to it, resulting in the right image and points:

[image]      [image]

I have tried looking at Gimps source code but it is way beyond my comprehension and I can not find any OpenCV routines that can do this.  Is there a way to apply a minimum radius smoothing to the 'non-edge' pixels of an edge mask in OpenCV???  By 'non-edge' I mean that as you can see Gimp does not radius these 'corners' (inside Yellow highlight) but only seems to apply the radius smoothing to edges 'inside' the image (Note: Gimps radiusing algorithm eliminates all the small islands in the mask which means that you don't have to find the largest area contour after cv2.findcontours is applied to get the points of interest):

[image]

2. Remove irrelevant array points from allpnts that are on the image edge.
3. Figure out why the array points that it finds seem to border around the green grass instead of the hard surface, I thought I was working with the hard surface hue.
4. Figure out why the hard surface color in CvKmeans2Color.bmp appears orange and not beige as in Gimps conversion AND why doesn't this match pixel for pixel with Gimps conversion? Here is CvKmeans2Color.bmp and Gimps:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: As of 5pm EST July 12, 2018:  I have resorted to the language I can most easily create code with, VB6, ughh, I know. Anyway I have been able to make a line/edge smoothing routine that works on the pixel level to do the min radius mask I want.  It works like a PacMan roaming along the right side of an edge as close at it can and leaves behind a breadcrumb trail on the Pac's left side.  Not sure I can make a python script from that code but at least I have a place to start as nobody has confirmed that there is an OpenCV alternative way to do it.  If anyone is interested [here](http://www.galaxyapps.us/RadiusEdge.zip) is a compiled .exe file that should run on most windows systems without an install (I think).  Here is a screenshot from it (Blue/GreenyBlue pixels are the unsmoothed edge and Green/GreenyBlue pixels are the radiused edge):

[image]

You can get the gist of my process logic by this VB6 routine:

```html
Sub BeginFollowingEdgePixel()
   Dim lastwasend As Integer
   wasinside = False
   While (1)
      If HitFrontBumper Then
         GoTo Hit
      Else
         Call MoveForward
      End If
      If circr = orgpos(0) And circc = orgpos(1) Then
         orgpixr = -1 'resets Start/Next button to begin at first first found blue edge pixel
         GoTo outnow 'this condition indicates that you have followed all blue edge pixels
      End If
      Call PaintUnderFrontBumperWhite
      Call PaintGreenOutsideLeftBumper
nomove:
      If NoLeftBumperContact Then
         Call MoveLeft
         Call PaintUnderLeftBumperWhite
         Call PaintGreenOutsideLeftBumper
         If NoLeftBumperContact Then
            If BackBumperContact Then
               Call MakeLeftTheNewForward
            End If
         End If
      ElseIf HitFrontBumper Then
Hit:
         Call PaintAheadOfForwardBumperGreen
         Call PaintGreenOutsideLeftSide
         Call MakeRightTheNewForward
         GoTo nomove
      Else
         Call PaintAheadOfForwardBumperGreen
         Call PaintGreenOutsideLeftSide
         Call PaintUnderFrontBumperWhite
      End If
      If (circr = 19 + circrad Or circr = -circrad Or circc = 19 + circrad Or circc = -circrad) Then
         If lastwasend = 0 And wasinside = True Then
            'finished following one edge pixel
            lastwasend = 1
            GoTo outnow
            Call redrawit
         End If
      Else
         If IsCircleInsideImage Then
            wasinside = True
         End If
         lastwasend = 0
      End If
      Pause (pausev) 'seconds between moves - Pressing Esc advances early
   Wend
outnow:
End Sub
```

Comment: I can also look at this one, but it may not happen until later tomorrow or Saturday morning as time permits. To clarify, you are just looking to find the bounding polygon of the largest green area?

Comment: Actually, trying to find another way to describe it, I find that my images are more reliably analysed selecting a range of hues around the largest Beige area (lower Hue value) in the ORIGINAL image. The shadows seem to affect the decision of which color to use. Then apply a radius filter on that mask and then make the mask into a polygon and then remove the appropriate polygon points so that the remaining points create a continuous path from from an edge point into the bitmap and then back to an edge point. Thanks

Comment: At some point I will have to deal with pausing the bot and have it wait for instructions when it reaches a gate in a fence.  Not sure how the algorithm will react in that case, I will get a picture of that case and add it.  I might just nail a red reflector down before it gets confused, at a gate or where my boat ramp enters the water etc. Would be very easy to add a scan for red reflector to the script.

Comment: Hard surface Red reflectors will likely be added at end of each section of hard surface to stop the bot.  There will also be an 'any direction' bump sensor to pause it and likely 'look' down sensors to stop it from going over a step or into the pool :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally had time to look at this. I will address each point of yours and then show the changes in the code. Let me know if you have any questions, or suggestions.

1. Looks like you were able to do this yourself well enough.

   1.a. This can be taken care of by blurring the image before doing any processing to it. The following changes to the code were made to accomplish this;

   ```
   ...
   start_time = time.time()                                              

   blur_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0) #here                        

   # Use kmeans to convert to 2 color image                              
   hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(blur_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   ...
   ```
2. I have changed the code to remove points that are on a line that perfectly follows the side of the image. It should be basically impossible for a grass edge to also coincide with this.

   ```
   ...
   allpnts = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)                          

   new_allpnts = []                                                      


   for i in range(len(allpnts)):                                         
       a = (i-1) % len(allpnts)                                          
       b = (i+1) % len(allpnts)                                          

       if ((allpnts[i,0,0] == 0 or allpnts[i,0,0] == (img.shape[1]-1)) and (allpnts[i,0,1] == 0 or allpnts[i,0,1] == (img.shape[0]-1))):          
           tmp1 = allpnts[a,0] - allpnts[i,0]                            
           tmp2 = allpnts[b,0] - allpnts[i,0]                                                                                                                     
           if not (0 in tmp1 and 0 in tmp2):                             
               new_allpnts.append(allpnts[i])
       else:
           new_allpnts.append(allpnts[i])
   ...
   cv2.drawContours(pntscanvas, new_allpnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
   ...
   ```
3. Due to how the contours are found in the image, we can simply flip the thresholding function and find the contour around the other part of the image. Changes are below;

   ```
   ...
   #Extract contours from the mask                                      
   ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #here      
   im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   ...
   ```
4. As for the color differences, you have converted your image into HSV format and before saving you are not switching it back to BGR. This change to HSV does give you better results so I would keep it, but it is a different palette. Changes are below;

   ```
   ...
   cv2.imshow('mask.bmp',mask)                                           
   res2 = cv2.cvtColor(res2, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)                          
   cv2.imwrite('CvKmeans2Color.bmp',res2)                                
   cv2.imshow('CvKmeans2Color.bmp',res2)
   ...
   ```

Disclaimer: These changes are based off of the python code from above. Any changes to the python code that are not in the provide code my render my changes ineffective.

Comment: Thanks for solving a lot on my issues but I do not think I can accept a Gaussian Blur as a duplicate/improvement of the Gimp procedure.  I worked with all kinds of blurs and filters in Gimp and had limited results in accuracy of Grass/Hard surface edge deviation error.  The blur does provide some smoothing at the expense of reducing the hue change gradient across the actual edge pixels which my eye can interpolate on the original image.  As a result, hue range for the inRange pixel selection that creates the mask will be less effective at finding the true path I want.  My quest continues...

Comment: In other words, the blur does not 'duplicate' the Gimp procedure as the Gimp procedure includes a radius smoothing on the mask and the blur is not an 'improvement' of the Gimp procedure for reasons above.

Comment: Also, 2. is not solved, because when I use all your code changes, I still get the extra 'red' array points that are at the image edge.  An actual solution for 2. would not be as simple as just removing all array points that are on the image corners because this would not work if the Grass/Hard surface line actually begins on an image corner.  I will work on this issue after I get some code/solution for a radiusing filter for the mask which works on the image of my 'Left to do' 1.

Comment: End of last sentence should read > ....works with a masks whose edging is as shown on the image of my 'Left to do' 1.

Comment: I've edited my answer on #2. Should remove points that are on the edges as long as both lines it is a part of follow the edge of the image. Working on #1.

Comment: BTW #2 currently only checks for corners as a contour wont have a point on a side that is on a straight line.

Comment: Good idea and code on #2!!  Try hsvdelta of 5 and you will see that we start getting many more 'red' points not on grass edge that would be removed with Gimps  'radius filter on edges' at 5 and even lower hsvdeltas.  We may have to have you edit your answer and me, edit my question with footnotes to keep talking and let others who are following see the progression of this.  If we move this to chat, can others follow us if they want to see our future conversing on this?

Comment: In chat they might, but I'm not sure.